# Cannot add or remove object to an Array in Firebase Firestore using Flutter

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add an object to an array in Firestore. My code is

```
Future signUpForClass(String docId, Member member) async {
    await _fireStoreInstance.collection("collection_name").doc(docId).update({
      "signedUpMembers": FieldValue.arrayUnion([member])
    });
  }
```

but I get an error saying: *Invalid argument: Instance of 'Member'*

When I check on the empty array in Firestore it seems like the type of the array is a String and I am able to use a string argument, i.e. member.name, and then I can add/remove from the array. However, when I create the document with the "signedUpMembers" array, I pass the array an empty list of Members, i.e. `"signedUpMembers": <Member>[]`

What am I doing wrong? I've tried a bunch of different syntax for this but I haven't been able to add the whole object to the array, only strings.

Comment: Pretty sure Firestore doesn't support storing your object. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: I think you need something like this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Yes. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Firestore only allows certain data-types (String, List, Map, GeoPoint, etc). To store your data, you should convert it to json/map.

```dart
class Member {

  String name;

  ...

  Map toJSON() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```